# Nest files in project explorer

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to know if Sublime Text has something (some plugin whatever) similar to "*Nest Related Files*" functionlity that we have in visual studio?

I would love to see something like that:

[image]

Comment: You can edit \*.sublime-project file to achieve this *manually*. [Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) is official page about projects.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasnt clear. I would like to "group" similar files as you see in this image. app.ts is my typescript and app.js and app.js.map is related files. In my system they are on same path, but visual studio 'group' them in soluction explorer.